# Canvas: How to plot a spiral around a specified purple dot from the specified orange dot to the specified green dot

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a spiral starting from a "start" point up to an "end point. The spiral also has a given center point so it can draw the spirals around that center point. 
I can't make it work, somehow the math is totally wrong.
Any advice on how to solve this?

[The jsfiddle of the code I tried is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/helloukw/behvrd16/3/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt = c.getContext("2d");

    //center of the spiral coords:
    var centerX = 400;
    var centerY = 300;

    //draw the center of spiral point:
    drawCirc(centerX, centerY, 10, '#6f0c4f');

    var gap = 8;
    var STEPS_PER_ROTATION = 50;
    var rotations = 4;
    var increment = rotations * Math.PI / STEPS_PER_ROTATION;
    var theta = increment;

    //start point:
    var startX = 500;
    var startY = 380;

    //end point:
    var endX = 600
    var endY = 300;

    //draw the start and end points as small circles:
    drawCirc(startX, startY, 6, '#FF0000');
    drawCirc(endX, endY, 6, '#00FF00');

    //trying to calculate theta start position:
    theta = Math.abs(((centerX - startX) / Math.cos(theta)) / gap);

    var ind = 0;
    while (theta < rotations * Math.PI * 2) {
      var newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta) * gap;
      var newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta) * gap;
      var ukwObj = { x: newX, y: newY };
      if (ind == 0) {
        //draw start point with differnt color to differentiate
        drawCirc(newX, newY, 2, 'orange');
      } else {
        drawCirc(newX, newY);
      }
      ind++;
      theta = theta + increment;
    }

    function drawCirc(x, y, radius = 2, stroke = '#000000') {
      cxt.beginPath();
      cxt.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      cxt.strokeStyle = stroke;
      cxt.stroke();
      cxt.fillStyle = stroke;
      cxt.fill();
    }

    cxt.stroke(); // draw the spiral
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of plotting a circle is:
Given a center `x,y`, a radius `r`, we can plot points belonging to the circle by calcultating their coordinates as follow: `px = x + r * Math.cos(angle)` and `py = y + r * Math.sin(angle)` when angle varies from 0 to `2* Math.PI`.
If `r` grows when angle varies, the we get an outward spiral (from angle 0 to angle 2*PI which is equivalent to 0).

For the problem at hand we need to calculate a start and end position of the spiral, in polar coordinates (distance, angle).
So we need to compute the start angle, start distance, end angle and end distance, and plot each point by gradually incrementing both the angle and the distance.

The initial theta calculation was wrong, I've changed it.

Then I needed to calculate the start distance between center and start point, and the end distance between center and end point.

During rotation, you progressivley goes from start distance to end distance.

The total angle distance should be `totalTheta = numberOfRotation * 2 * Math.PI + (endAngle - startAngle)`, I replaced `rotations * Math.PI * 2` by `totalTheta`)

Just for fun and to demonstrate it works for any intial condition, I've randomized start position, end position and number of rotations slightly.

I've also decremented the angle increment at each iteration to make the distance between each point look more even, but you can comment to keep a constant angular speed.

**The solution below will randomly choose an orange dot, a green dot, a number of turns to complete the spiral, and will plot the spiral around the fixed purple dot.**

```js
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt = c.getContext("2d");

    //center of the spiral coords:
    var centerX = 200;
    var centerY = 150;

    //draw the center of spiral point:
    drawCirc(centerX, centerY, 10, '#6f0c4f');

    var gap = 8;
    var STEPS_PER_ROTATION = 50;
    var rotations = 1 + parseInt(Math.random() * 5, 10);
    var increment = rotations * Math.PI / STEPS_PER_ROTATION;
    var theta = increment;
    var dist = 0;

    //start point:
    var startX = centerX + (Math.random() * 150 - 75);
    var startY = centerY + (Math.random() * 150 - 75);
    var startAngleOffset = startX > centerX ? (startY > centerY ? 0 : 0) : (startY > centerY ? Math.PI : Math.PI);
    var startAngleSign = startX > centerX ? (startY > centerY ? 1 : -1) : (startY > centerY ? -1 : 1);

    //end point:
    var endX = centerX + (Math.random() * 150 - 75);
    var endY = centerY + (Math.random() * 150 - 75);
    var endAngleOffset = endX > centerX ? (endY > centerY ? 0 : 0) : (endY > centerY ? Math.PI : Math.PI);
    var endAngleSign = endX > centerX ? (endY > centerY ? 1 : -1) : (endY > centerY ? -1 : 1);

    //draw the start and end points as small circles:
    drawCirc(startX, startY, 6, '#FF0000');
    drawCirc(endX, endY, 6, '#00FF00');

    var startTheta = theta = startAngleOffset + startAngleSign * Math.atan(Math.abs(startY - centerY)/Math.abs(startX - centerX));

    var endTheta = endAngleOffset + endAngleSign * Math.atan(Math.abs(endY - centerY)/Math.abs(endX - centerX));

    var totalTheta = rotations * 2 * Math.PI + (endTheta - startTheta)
    dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(startY - centerY, 2) + Math.pow(startX - centerX, 2));

    finalDist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endY - centerY, 2) + Math.pow(endX - centerX, 2));
    var ind = 0;
    while (theta -startTheta < totalTheta) {
      var currentDist = (dist + ((finalDist - dist)* ((theta - startTheta) / (totalTheta))));
      var newX = centerX + currentDist * Math.cos(theta);
      var newY = centerY + currentDist * Math.sin(theta);
      var ukwObj = { x: newX, y: newY };
      if (ind == 0) {
        //draw start point with differnt color to differentiate
        drawCirc(newX, newY, 2, 'orange');
      } else {
        drawCirc(newX, newY);
      }
      ind++;
      theta = theta + increment;
      // decrement increment to make the space between points look more regular
      increment = Math.max(0.01, increment - 0.00096);
    }

    function drawCirc(x, y, radius = 2, stroke = '#000000') {
      cxt.beginPath();
      cxt.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      cxt.strokeStyle = stroke;
      cxt.stroke();
      cxt.fillStyle = stroke;
      cxt.fill();
    }

    cxt.stroke(); // draw the spiral
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: The code fails sometimes (blocks the browser). I may have introduced a mathematical instability by playing with the code too much. But you should be able to figure it out...

Comment: Yes, I think it has to do with rotations being random. Crashes if I set it to a number < 3.

Comment: I think that because the inrement can become negative and the angle never reach the end. change `increment -= 0.00096;` to `increment = Math.max(0.01, increment - 0.00096)` or comment this line to fix.

Comment: That was the problem, I've added the fix to the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work fine if start and end are in other places.

Comment: Modified the answer to  make it work for ANY start and end position.

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much!